# Plot factor levels with superscript text

Tags: r, ggplot2

Does anyone know how I can plot factor levels containing text with superscripts? In the example below I would like to have `A^1` and `B^3` in the x-axis as superscript text (without '^')

```r
# Fake dataframe
size <- 20

df <- data.frame(grp = sample(c("A^1", "B^3", "C"), size = size, replace = TRUE),
                 value = rnorm(size, mean = 10, sd = 1)) %>%
  mutate(grp = as.factor(grp)) %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(value, na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()

# barplot
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = grp, y = mean)) +
    geom_col()
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `ggtext::element_markdown`

```r
# install.packages('ggtext')

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = grp, y = mean)) +
  geom_col() +
  theme(axis.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `expression` and specify manually your labels:

```
xlabels <- c("A^1" = expression("A"^1), "B^3" = expression("B"^3), "C" = "C")

# barplot
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = grp, y = mean)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = xlabels)
```

[image]

Check out this link: https://statisticsglobe.com/add-subscript-and-superscript-to-plot-in-r